# Can maven run multiple Testng.xml which located in different classpath?

Tags: xml, maven, testng

I have a problem in running multiple testng.xml files with my maven. Below is my project structure.

Test-Automation

- TestA

  - Functional

    ```
     - FunctionA

         -FunctionATestNg.xml

     - FunctionB

         -FunctionBTestNg.xml
    ```
  - UI

    ```
     - UI1

         -UI1TestNg.xml
    ```

testAPom.xml

Question: I am trying to run FunctionATestNg.xml, FunctionBTestNg.xml, and UI1TestNg.xml from testAPom.xml.
The command i used is: mvn test -f TestA -Dsources= FunctionATestNg.xml,FunctionBTestNg.xml,and UI1TestNg.xml

Note: I am using maven-surefire-plugin to execute this.
However, at the end of the run, maven was not able to detect my testng.xml location. Is there any way to run multiple Testng.xml files with multiple locations?

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJxqJ.png)

Edit: For clearer understanding of my problem:
I need to have a pom file that can accept passed in parameters from users and run tests based on the passed in executions or run default test suites.
What i have done so far:
I used properties like `<properties><sources>xxx.xml,yyy.xml</sources></properties>` in pom file and on running surefire, i have included `<suiteXmlFile>${sources}</suiteXmlFile>`
However, due to the xml files are in different sub modules and locations, if user or the default value written passed in 2 or more xml name which are located in different module, surefire plugin will not be able to detect and run xml file as it should be

Comment: That would be great if you attach the project structure image in the question. As per my understanding TestA is the maven project and you have three different folders FunctionA, FunctionB and UI1( I'm unsure about what Functional and UI is as per the hierarchy ). In those three folders, you have different testng.xml and you have to run those suite files from  pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample parent pom.xml content. Just change the name of suite file to default "testng.xml" in all maven modules and then run following maven command:

```
mvn clean test -pl functional-a,functional-b,UI
```

Note: Above functional-a,functional-b,UI are the module names

**Parent Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>frostyaxe</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>functional-a</module>
        <module>functional-b</module>
        <module>UI</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <version>2.14.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                               <outputDirectory>${basedir}\target</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi UnknownBeast. Thanks for your reply.
I have attached my project structure for better clarification.
I actually have the need to run BasicChecks.xml and StartGameDSFTest.xml from test-automation's pom file. And while running that 2 xml files, other modules like dsf-center-Platforms has their own xml and i would like maven to skip all test in other modules except for the ones that i have passed in.

Comment: Some clarification:
1. If i put only BasicChecks.xml in my pom file then it can work.
2. If i put both BasicChecks.xml and another modules's (for example from dsf-center-Platforms' testng.xml), it can't work.

Comment: Hi Mate, I have updated the answer. Please check that and let me know if you face any issue while configuring the parent pom with the sub modules.

Comment: Hi UnknownBeast, thanks for taking the time to answer to my question. I think there are some misunderstanding in my question. I am sorry for that. I have updated my question for clearer understanding.